# Is there built in method to get all __annotations__ from all base classes in Python?

Tags: python, types, annotations

We have builtin `dir()` function to get all attributes available for class or instance, defined in based classes.

Is there same for **annotations**? I'd like to have `get_annotations()` function, which works like this:

```
def get_annotations(cls: type): ...  # ?


class Base1:
    foo: float


class Base2:
    bar: int


class A(Base1, Base2):
    baz: str


assert get_annotations(A) == {'foo': float, 'bar': int, 'baz': str}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, right?

```
def get_annotations(cls: type):
    all_ann = [c.__annotations__ for c in cls.mro()[:-1]]
    all_ann_dict = dict()
    for aa in all_ann[::-1]:
        all_ann_dict.update(**aa) 
return all_ann_dict

get_annotations(A)
# {'bar': int, 'foo': float, 'baz': str}
```

Or a one-liner version of it:

```
get_annotations = lambda cls: {k:v for c in A.mro()[:-1][::-1] for k,v in c.__annotations__.items()}

get_annotations(A)
# {'bar': int, 'foo': float, 'baz': str}
```